# How should I approach a possible title error on my resume with a potential employer?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, job-change, human-resources, job-description

I just had a final interview for a manager level position with a new employer and might have another next week. But after looking over my resume I realized that my first job out of college might be incorrect! This was a position 8.5 years ago and I remembered that I applied for a Jr. Financial Analyst position but my title when I started was Sr. Accounting Tech. HR told me that it was a grading error and that they would fix it, but I never double checked. Now I'm worried that if I get the job and and they run my employment history it will look like I lied. I never had to do this check because I've been with my second company since I moved on.

What should I do? Should I double check with my former employer? And if my resume is incorrect should I let the new company's HR know? Or is it a non-issue??

Pleas help! Thank you!!

Comment: The two positions are the same grade and responsibility. The only difference is the title.

Comment: Non issue. This is not worth losing sleep over. Or worrying at all, actually.

Comment: "HR told me that it was a grading error and that they would fix it" - What do you mean by this? If you want to fix your CV, you can just do it. What action do you need your previous employer to take to "fix" it?

Answer (score 7):

They would not care about this . The only thing they check is if you worked for that duration in companies as titles vary in the company. The position you mention is so far down in the past that it will not matter.
By the way , the people doing the background checks are not the ones who interview. Do not sweat it , it is a non issue

Comment: When calling references or doing background checks, we do check titles - although this is more to ensure that the person applying for a senior developer role wasn't a cleaner at the last job he said he was programming at. Then again, if someone said they were senior developer, but was title systems architect, I would just move on to checking responsibilities.